# Preposition for author of a book: "de" or "par"

Tags: prépositions

What is the correct preposition to use for the author of a book? For example, *Hamlet by William Shakespeare*. I thought it would be **par** (*Hamlet par William Shakespeare*) but I've seen many examples of **de** (*Hamlet de William Shakespeare*).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The preposition is *de* when the book or other work is not mentioned by name.

> un livre de Balzac
>   cette chanson de Renaud
>   le premier film de Renoir

The preposition is *par* when the origin of the work is expressed by a verb in the passive voice.

> un livre écrit par Balzac
>   cette chanson composée par Renaud
>   le premier film tourné par Renoir

When the title is mentioned, it is common that two interpretations are possible: a work “of” (i.e. by) an author; or a work written (or composed, etc.) by the author, where the verb is omitted.

> *Le Colonel Chabert* de Balzac  **or**  *Le Colonel Chabert*, par Balzac
>   *Déserteur* de Renaud  **or**  *Déserteur*, par Renaud
>   *La Fille de l'eau* de Renoir  **or**  *La Fille de l'eau*, par Renoir

There can be exceptions, but usually, when the title and the author form a noun phrase, *de* is used. The preposition *par* is used when the author indication is a subtitle to the title (it's what you'd put on a book cover, if you put a preposition at all) or a parenthetical remark.

> *Le Colonel Chabert*, par Balzac, est un hommage aux soldats de Napoléon.
>   Je lis *Le Colonel Chabert* de Balzac.

For works that have multiple authors, such as films and songs, the preposition *par* is rarely used unless the role of the authors is explicited (*un film de Renoir* vs. *un film réalisé par Renoir*).

Comment: _Le déserteur_ de Vian, par Renaud.

Answer (score 3):

*« de »* is probably the form you're searching for.

*« par »* is far less common in this context, it's mostly used for adaptations (a movie adapted from a book, for example) or interpretations (musical or theatrical performance, ...).

But I guess it would be understood anyway, and cannot actually be said "incorrect".

Answer (score 2):

Both *par* and *de* are quite accepted, and I can't see any reason or context why you couldn't use one or the other, as long as we are talking about a theater/poetry work, since it bears a bit of a "classical" and old-fashioned connotation.

For any other artistic production (novels, song, painting, movie, etc...) I would tend to use *de*.